# Optimise crosscheck function of big pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, optimization

I'm struggling with the optimisation of a program that I wrote to check if a client in a list is also in another list.

```
for index1, person1 in list1.iterrows():
    for referent in list(clients_dict.keys()):
        for index_client, client in clients_dict[referent].iterrows():
            match = checkPersonMatches(person1,
                                       client,
                                       fuzz_ratio_threshold)
```

This is the loop I'm doing, which is very inefficient.

My list1 is a pandas DataFrame of shape (nb_of_clients, 7), with each column representing:
LastName, OldName, FirstName, BirthDate, Sex, DeathDate, Week

The client_dict is a Dictionary of shape {referent: DataFrame}
Each DataFrame in this dictionary has shape (nb_of_clients, 3) with each column representing:
FullName, Birthdate, Others.

Is there a better way, probably using numpy or pandas, to apply my checkPersonMatches() function to every possible pair of elements in all of these lists?

Thanks!